# Loop through json results to create a list

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I retrieve json results using $.post() and I'd like to be able to print into a list for each result.

Using the following only displays the last json item

**JQUERY**

```
$.post('/assets/inc/account-info.php', qString, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    var datas = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(datas);
    $("#note").append("<li>id=recordsarray_"+datas.id+"><a href='#"+datas.id+"'>"+datas.name+"</a></li>");  
});
```

Comment: please post the content of your datas variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are getting array of objects in frontend and this object have id and name in it :

```
// To put data directly in html you can do this :
    $.each(datas,function(i,data){
       $("#note").append("<li>id=recordsarray_"+data.id+"><a href='#"+data.id+"'>"+data.name+"</a></li>");
    });

 OR

// To Put your data in array you can do this :
    var arr = [];
    // This will help you putting the json object in to array
    $.each(datas,function(i,data){
       arr.push({id:data.id, name:data.name});   
    });

    // once you get the array you can loop through it and add it to your html:
    for (i=0;i<arr.length;i++){ 
        $("#note").append("<li>id=recordsarray_"+arr[i].id+"><a href='#"+arr[i].id+"'>"+arr[i].name+"</a></li>");
    });   
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the data by index and set then grab the id & name for each one.
I'm also assuming (since you said list) that you have multiple levels to your Data.

```
$.each(datas, function() {
    $.each(this, function(key, value) {
        $("#note").append("<li id=recordsarray_" + 
             datas[key].id + "><a href='#" + 
             datas[key].id + "'>" + 
             datas[key].name + "</a></li>"
        );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(datas).each(function(){ $("#note").append("<li>id=recordsarray_"+this.id+"><a href='#"+this.id+"'>"+this.name+"</a></li>"); });
```

Comment: This will work?  I thought you have to use the $.each function instead since these aren't jQuery Objects?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$.each(datas, function(i,item){
    $("#note").append("<li>id=recordsarray_"+datas[i].id+"><a href='#"+datas[i].id+"'>"+datas[i].name+"</a></li>");
});
```